# Huge video duration after PGS subtitles burn onto video

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, overlay

i'm trying to burn subtitles onto video stream and something weird happens.
This is my video file before the process:

```
ffprobe version N-107936-gf99d15cca0-20220829 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.55_3defb7b)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220829
  libavutil      57. 34.100 / 57. 34.100
  libavcodec     59. 42.103 / 59. 42.103
  libavformat    59. 30.100 / 59. 30.100
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 46.103 /  8. 46.103
  libswscale      6.  8.104 /  6.  8.104
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
[matroska,webm @ 000001c78f4b7600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf59.4.101
  Duration: 00:42:12.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15079 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 378.878500
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 378.878500, end 764.805708
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 764.805708, end 1122.496375
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 1122.496375, end 1688.395042
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1688.395042, end 2488.152333
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 2488.152333, end 2532.544000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 06
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 3998894
      DURATION-eng    : 00:42:12.530000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 60720
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1265915067
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v35.0.0 ('All The Love In The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-08-10 23:19:05
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      ENCODER         : Lavc59.4.100 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:42:12.530000000
  Stream #0:1(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 191999
      DURATION-eng    : 00:42:12.566000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 59357
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 60781327
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v35.0.0 ('All The Love In The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-08-10 23:19:05
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      ENCODER         : Lavc59.4.100 ac3
      DURATION        : 00:42:12.611000000
  Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      title           : Forced
      BPS-eng         : 27372
      DURATION-eng    : 00:00:10.969000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 8
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 37531
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v35.0.0 ('All The Love In The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-08-10 23:19:05
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:12:08.728000000
```

And after i execute
`ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v][0:s]overlay[v]" -map [v] -map 0:1 -c:v libx264 -crf 13 -c:a copy "Muxed\output.mkv"`

i get this

```
ffprobe version N-107936-gf99d15cca0-20220829 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.55_3defb7b)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220829
  libavutil      57. 34.100 / 57. 34.100
  libavcodec     59. 42.103 / 59. 42.103
  libavformat    59. 30.100 / 59. 30.100
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 46.103 /  8. 46.103
  libswscale      6.  8.104 /  6.  8.104
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf59.30.100
  Duration: 1193:14:56.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 378.878500
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 378.878500, end 764.805708
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 764.805708, end 1122.496375
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 1122.496375, end 1688.395042
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1688.395042, end 2488.152333
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 2488.152333, end 2532.544000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 06
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc59.42.103 libx264
      DURATION        : 1193:14:56.07200000
  Stream #0:1(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 191999
      DURATION-eng    : 00:42:12.566000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 59357
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 60781327
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v35.0.0 ('All The Love In The World') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-08-10 23:19:05
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      ENCODER         : Lavc59.4.100 ac3
      DURATION        : 00:42:12.611000000
```

I get the subtitles correctly burned but with a video duration of 1193 hours.
I looked around the whole internet to find a similar problem but nothing.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v][0:s]overlay=shortest=1[v]" -map [v] -map 0:1 -c:v libx264 -crf 13 -c:a copy "Muxed\output.mkv"`. You may also try other version of FFmpeg. Why are you using version `N-107936-gf99d15cca0-20220829`?

Comment: i downloaded a windows build, don't really know what should i use. I'll try a different version.

Comment: Try version: 5.1 `ffmpeg-release-full.7z` from [www.gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/)

Comment: The truth is i did try the `=shortest=1` option but it was't recognized cause i had the wrong ffmpeg version probably. Now that i installed the version you suggested i got a correct duration output with that command! Thank you!